# What is the best method to secure requests based on an Active Directory authentication solution

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I have a problem for a backend solution developpement. I need someone to guide me.

I'm developping a backend solution with SpringBoot.

My backend should :

1. Connect to an Active Directory
2. Use a token system for the security part
3. Give special access for each request (based on AD group)

After a lot of tests and research, I already have this :

**Connect to an Active Directory**

For the connection to AD part, I did this :

Inside a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adProvider
                = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("domain.com", "ldap", "ou,dc");
        adProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
        adProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
        adProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(adProvider);
    }
```

`userDetailsContextMapper()` simply maps the info to an user class that contains the `username`, the `lastname` and the list `memberOf` of the user (AD groups).

**Using token**

I use this method for the token. It works too.

```
     public SignedJWT getToken(String username) {
        JWSSigner signer = null;

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] sharedSecret = new byte[32];
        random.nextBytes(sharedSecret);

        signer = new MACSigner(sharedSecret);

        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                .subject(username)
                .issuer("domain")
                .expirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000))
                .build();    
        SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256), claimsSet);
        signedJWT.sign(signer);   
        String serializedToken = signedJWT.serialize();

        return signedJWT;
               
   }
```

**Access per request**

For the third part I want to give access to a specific request only for a given AD group.

Imagine I have two correctly mapped request :

`domain.com/sales/2022/all`  : Return all the sales values for the year 2022
`domain.com/IT/inventory/all`: Return all the IT inventory

I want only the people that are from the group `IT` that can get a result from the IT's request and for the sale's request, only someone who is a member of the groupe `sales`.

But first of all, I want only people who are authenticated and have a valid token who can call a request.

I searched and tested different solutions on the internet but I did not find anything compatible with my two previous method.

Can you help me ? I'm not specially looking for a solution, a link to a good documentation or some example are enough for me.

Comment: Write a proper spring boot expression.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Write a proper spring boot expression for what? The requests ? The connections?

Comment: Sorry that should have been spring security not sprign boot. You are using Spring Security, then write an expression that one needs to be authenticated to access your application.

Comment: Can you give me any example please?

Comment: There are plenty examples in the reference guide or other spring security related questions. That is the `http.authorizeRequest` stuff that should be in your configuration.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I have this for the moment `http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()` (no permissions). I don't know how to add authenticated user (with my AD authentication). This is the part that gives me a bit of a problem. I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I didn't find any documentation that explains clearly how `http.authorizeRequest` works and how to use each method.

Comment: `/` is only ther oot URL nothing underneath. add `anyRequest().authenticated()` I would also strongly suggest a read of the Spring Security documentation

Comment: The [Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html) explains this fairly well. There is also [an overview of all expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/expression-based.html) you can use.

Comment: I tried this. The problem is that I don't know how to authenticated my user. I used to use this `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated() .and() .formLogin()`. But it opens me. I want the form login the be in frontend side (be authenticated with a request) . I'll check the documentation, thank you.

Comment: You don't need the `formLogin`... That is what you get from copy / pasting code.

Comment: Yes I know. It was just easier for me for testing. But I'll check your doc. Thank you.